# GWT Editor Framework : custom LeafValueEditor implementing HasEditorErrors

Tags: gwt, validation, bean-validation

I have implemented my own form field as `IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<String>>` that I'd like to use in the forms of my application.

```
public class FormField extends Composite implements IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<String>> {

    interface FormFieldUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, FormField> {
    }

    private static FormFieldUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(FormFieldUiBinder.class);

    interface FormFieldStyle extends CssResource {
        String error();
    }

    @UiField
    TextBox wrapped;

    private String placeholder;

    public FormField() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        wrapped.setTitle("");
    }

    @UiHandler("wrapped")
    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
        Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                wrapped.selectAll();
            }
        });
    }

    public String getText() {
        return wrapped.getText();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
            wrapped.setText(text);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current placeholder text for the text box.
     * 
     * @return the current placeholder text
     */
    public String getPlaceholder() {
        return placeholder;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the placeholder text displayed in the text box.
     * 
     * @param placeholder
     *            the placeholder text
     */
    public void setPlaceholder(String text) {
        placeholder = (text != null ? text : "");
        wrapped.getElement().setPropertyString("placeholder", placeholder);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return wrapped.getTitle();
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        wrapped.setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public LeafValueEditor<String> asEditor() {
        return wrapped.asEditor();
    }

    public int getVisibleLength() {
        return wrapped.getVisibleLength();
    }

    public void setVisibleLength(int length) {
        wrapped.setVisibleLength(length);
    }

    public boolean isReadOnly() {
        return wrapped.isReadOnly();
    }

    public void setReadOnly(boolean readOnly) {
        wrapped.setReadOnly(readOnly);
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return wrapped.isEnabled();
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        wrapped.setEnabled(enabled);
    }

    public void setWidth(String width) {
        wrapped.setWidth(width);
    }

}
```

The corresponding UIBinder file is plain simple :

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:TextBox ui:field="wrapped" />
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

This works smoothly in the forms I create like this :

```
<g:AbsolutePanel width="350px" height="225px"
    styleName="{res.css.inputArea}">
    <g:at left='10' top='0'>
        <g:HTMLPanel width="350px">
            <h1>Personalia</h1>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:at>
    <g:at left='10' top='65'>
        <f:FormLabel text="voornaam" />
    </g:at>
    <g:at left='10' top='80'>
        <f:FormField ui:field="firstName" placeholder="voornaam" />
    </g:at>
    <g:at left='10' top='115'>
        <f:FormLabel text="achternaam" />
    </g:at>
    <g:at left='10' top='130'>
        <f:FormField ui:field="lastName" placeholder="achternaam"/>
    </g:at>
</g:AbsolutePanel>
```

In my views, I can then use the EditorDriver like this :

```
interface EditorDriver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<Account, AccountPersonaliaEditor> {
}
private final EditorDriver editorDriver = GWT.create(EditorDriver.class);
```

And populating the form works fine too

```
    editorDriver.initialize(editor);
    editorDriver.edit(presenter.getAccount());
```

As well as getting the values after editing :

```
Account account = editorDriver.flush();
```

Now I would like to implement feedback on the errors. I have the **GWT Bean validation** framework working fine too. I just need to show the errors.

So, what I am trying next, is to have the FormField **implement HasEditorErrors**. Here is my problem/question.

```
public class FormField extends Composite implements IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<String>>, HasEditorErrors<String>
```

As soon as I implement this interface (even with a empty implementation), I run into the following compile time error :

```
[DEBUG] [klawtapp] - Rebinding com.example.screen.ui.center.AccountPersonaliaImpl.EditorDriver
    [DEBUG] [klawtapp] - Invoking generator com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.SimpleBeanEditorDriverGenerator
        [DEBUG] [klawtapp] - Creating Editor model for com.example.screen.ui.center.AccountPersonaliaImpl.EditorDriver
            [DEBUG] [klawtapp] - Descending into firstName
                [ERROR] [klawtapp] - Could not find a getter for path wrapped in proxy type java.lang.String
            [DEBUG] [klawtapp] - Descending into lastName
                [ERROR] [klawtapp] - Could not find a getter for path wrapped in proxy type java.lang.String
            [ERROR] [klawtapp] - Unable to create Editor model due to previous errors
[ERROR] [klawtapp] - Deferred binding failed for 'com.example.screen.ui.center.AccountPersonaliaImpl.EditorDriver'; expect subsequent failures
```

This seemed so trivial. I have tried adding getter/setter for wrapped but that does not really help.

**EDIT:** for a moment, I thought the solution would be to implement `HasEditorErrors<LeafValueEditor<String>>` instead of `HasEditorErrors<String>` to prevent descending the hierarchy to the wrapped TextBox, but the results are similar :

```
            [ERROR] [klawtapp] - Could not find a getter for path wrapped in proxy type com.google.gwt.editor.client.LeafValueEditor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply annotate your `wrapped` text box with `@Editor.Ignore`.

Alternatively, you could remove the `implements IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<String>>` and instead annotate the `wrapped` field with `@Path("")` (you'll have to test with `null` values though if you might face them, as I'm not sure it'll work well as-is).

Or you could choose to implement your own `LeafValueEditor<String>` instead of relying on the one from the `TextBox`.

Comment: Thanks. That works, or at least compiles/generates, but the editorDriver always reports no errors, while using the validator 'manually', the violations are reported correctly. Any idea ?

Comment: I implemented HasEditorErrors<String> for the FormField class and added @Editor.Ignore to the wrapped TextBox.

Comment: I believe you *have* to use the validator "manually" (there's no "integration" with the Editor framework AFAIK) and call `setConstraintViolations` on the `EditorDriver`.

Comment: Ok, I see. The javadoc seems to imply this is automatic, see "boolean hasErrors" => Indicates if the last call to {@link #flush()} resulted in any errors. But the call to flush() does not affect the errors at all.

Comment: These are errors generated by the editors themselves (`reportError` on the `EditorDelegate`; `IntegerBox` will generate one such error for instance if you type something in the box that cannot be parsed as an integer)